# Visual Studio Code Scroll Typing Cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When editing a cell (Jupyter ipynb notebook) in VS Code, if I scroll up or down I cannot type in the cell until I am scrolled back. Essentially the selected cell needs to be in the window. I remain in editor mode the entire time, and once I scroll back down, the cursor remains in the same location. I can press the up or down arrow at that point and it will move lines.

This is possibly a Jupyter notebook issue or a VS Code one. Does anyone know what the setting would be for this? Ultimately I am looking for a way to modify an 'edited' cell when it is not in the window (eg scrolled above or below)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly this is the same issue I am having even now with my laptop mouse. I can scroll up while selecting code/text but not scroll down. This can be resolved with a mouse that has a wheel or you can try holding shift button and pressing arrow buttons up or down.